# change the annotation for node-selector for openshift namespace

Tags: docker, kubernetes, openshift, openshift-origin

I want to create projects on a particular node on openshift using the rest api.

I call the openshift api `/oapi/v1/projectrequests` to create projects.
And in the body I am sending,

```
    body:
    {
        apiVersion: 'v1',
        kind: 'ProjectRequest',
        metadata: {
            name: projectName,
            annotations: {
                "openshift.io/node-selector": "servicelevel=botifyproject",
            }
        },
```

This api runs successfully, project gets created but when I run the command,
`oc describr project <project-name>` it doesn't show me anything that says it is inside the botifyproject node selector.

Is this the wrong way of doing this?

Comment: You need to deploy something. It is the pods which will get scheduled to specific nodes, presuming that that annotation on the project controls that. What docs are you reading that says it is done that way.

Comment: I took some help from my colleagues who are working on openshift. But this way doesn't work. What do you mean by "You need to deploy something". I thought at the time of namespace creation, if i define the node-selector, all the pods created inside would be allocated in that node-selector only? Was I wrong to think in this way?

Comment: You said you were doing ``oc describe project``. There was nothing to suggest you had deployed any pods to work out where they landed.

Comment: Some related information about the topic can be found at https://blog.openshift.com/deploying-applications-to-specific-nodes/

Comment: oh, No I had created a project and deployed the pods as well, apologies for the miscommunication. By creating the project i mean, i have deployed 5 pods on that project

Comment: And https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.9/admin_guide/managing_projects.html#using-node-selectors and https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.9/dev_guide/deployments/basic_deployment_operations.html#assigning-pods-to-specific-nodes

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton we are using openshift 3.6. And, I am using templates to create projects using openshift rest apis, should i add this node-selector key to all the deployment configs?

Comment: Setting a project wide node selector is described in https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.9/admin_guide/managing_projects.html#setting-the-project-wide-node-selector. The question is, have the nodes been labelled by cluster admin with ``servicelevel=botifyproject`` to begin with. If you are needing to use ``ProjectRequest``, are you saying no ``openshift.io/node-selector`` annotation is getting added to your project when created.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174476/discussion-between-ayush-ojha-and-graham-dumpleton).

Comment: Sorry, I don't use SO chat. You may be better off asking on one of the lists at https://lists.openshift.redhat.com/openshiftmm/listinfo if you want to have a discussion with someone about it.